# Scala Map from tuple iterable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Constructing `scala.collection.Map` from other collections, I constantly find myself writing:

```
val map = Map(foo.map(x=>(x, f(x)))
```

However, this doesn't really work since `Map.apply` takes variable arguments only - so I have to write:

```
val map = Map(foo.map(x=>(x, f(x)) toSeq :_*)
```

to get what I want, but that seems painful. Is there a prettier way to construct a `Map` from an `Iterable` of tuples?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `TraversableOnce.toMap` which is defined if the elements of a Traversable/Iterable are of type `Tuple2`. [(API)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce)

```
val map = foo.map(x=>(x, f(x)).toMap
```

Comment: Or, `foo.mapValues(f).toMap`.

Comment: @missingfaktor is mapValues a method to classes other than Map?

Comment: @mayonesa, no, but I guess I didn't know any better at the time! :)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use use `collection.breakOut` as the implicit `CanBuildFrom` argument to the `map` call; this will pick a result builder based on the expected type.

```
scala> val x: Map[Int, String] = (1 to 5).map(x => (x, "-" * x))(collection.breakOut)
x: Map[Int,String] = Map(5 -> -----, 1 -> -, 2 -> --, 3 -> ---, 4 -> ----)
```

It will perform better than the `.toMap` version, as it only iterates the collection once.

It's not so obvious, but this also works with a for-comprehension.

```
scala> val x: Map[Int, String] = (for (i <- (1 to 5)) yield (i, "-" * i))(collection.breakOut)
x: Map[Int,String] = Map(5 -> -----, 1 -> -, 2 -> --, 3 -> ---, 4 -> ----)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - while I'm not going to use it in code that other people have to read without pasting in links to the numerous explanations to the `CanBuildFrom` craziness, it *is* useful for the case where I want to convert an immutable range to a `mutable.Map`, where the answer I accepted before just gives me a type error.

Answer (score 2):

```
val map = foo zip (foo map f) toMap
```